# Does geom_abline(...) plot data multiple times?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does using `geom_abline(...)` (as well as `geom_vline` and `geom_hline`) result in multiple overplotting of the same line when used "naively"?

For example, say we are interested in the following faceted scatterplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

k <- 4
data.frame(id = letters[1:k], 
           m = rnorm(k), 
           b = rnorm(k))[rep(1:k, 30),] %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(n()),
         eps = 0.1*rnorm(n()),
         y = m*x + b + eps) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ id) ->
  p
```

The easiest way to add an ab-line to it is as follows:

```
print(p + geom_abline(aes(slope = m, intercept = b), color = 'red'))
```

Is that the "right way" to do it? In particular, doesn't the above plot the ab-line 30 times in each facet?  For example this makes it seem like it does:

```
print(p + geom_abline(aes(slope = m, intercept = b + eps), color = 'red'))
```

If so, is it better to do something like this?

```
print(p + geom_abline(aes(slope = m, intercept = b), 
                      data = Z %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(m = unique(m), b = unique(b)),
                      color = 'red'))
```

Note that this produces something visually indistiguishable from the first plot. My question is about the right way to use these ggplot functions.

Comment: `geom_abline` [makes your data unique](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-abline.r#L121). So no 30x overplotting.

Comment: @lukeA That is a very relevant point! In fact, I feel that it is really the anwer to my question. If you make it a full answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_abline` takes care already of multiple lines at the same spot by making the values unique. You can also verify that by running e.g. `p + geom_abline(aes(slope = m, intercept = b), color = 'red', alpha = .1)` - if it were 30 lines at the same spot, they would be opaque.