# Plot multiple lines with the geom_abline() ggplot2 function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with the intercepts and slopes for six lines. There are other questions that address this (i.e., this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287549/does-geom-abline-plot-data-multiple-times)), but when I follow the same approach, it doesn't seem to work.

When I try the following, a plot with only a single line is returned:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,                 ~b0,                ~b1,
  1L,  -0.253642820580212, 0.0388815148531228,
  2L,  -0.247859980353316, 0.0462798786249876,
  3L,  -0.241628306421253, 0.0418616653609702,
  4L,  -0.476161762130615, 0.0216251842526953,
  5L,  -0.372079433686108, 0.0564612163378217,
  6L, -0.0983318344106016, 0.0759661386473856
)

ggplot(d, aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1)) +
  geom_abline() +
  xlim(0, 10) +
  ylim(0, 10)
```

[image: plot with one line]

How can I plot the six lines associated with the six intercepts and slopes?

Comment: From `?geom_abline`: "Unlike most other geoms, these geoms do not inherit aesthetics from the plot default, because they do not understand x and y aesthetics".

Answer (score 4):

```
ggplot(d)  +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1, color=factor(ID))) +
  xlim(0, 100) +
  ylim(0, 10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do:

```
library(tibble)

d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,                 ~b0,                ~b1,
  1L,  -0.253642820580212, 0.0388815148531228,
  2L,  -0.247859980353316, 0.0462798786249876,
  3L,  -0.241628306421253, 0.0418616653609702,
  4L,  -0.476161762130615, 0.0216251842526953,
  5L,  -0.372079433686108, 0.0564612163378217,
  6L, -0.0983318344106016, 0.0759661386473856
)

ggplot(d) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1, group = "ID")) +
  xlim(0, 10) +
  ylim(0, 10)
```

Not sure about the limits though

Answer (score 3):

You just want to move the `aes` to `geom_abline`.  That is

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1)) +
  xlim(0, 10) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

I hope this helps!